# Javascript canvas rotate image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a image with exif orientation at 6! I'm scaling the image in canvas (to reduce with proportion)
like this:

```
var width = $('#thumbnail').css('width')
    var heigth = $('#thumbnail').css('height')
    console.log(width);
    console.log(heigth);
    $('#thumbnail').css('height', width).css('width', heigth);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0, c.width/2, c.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI/180);
    ctx.translate(c.width/2, c.height/2);

    ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2, -img.height/2);

    ctx.restore();
```

The canvas size is the image size reduce by ratio.
But the result is not expected. The picture is scaled to 200% (zoom-in).

If have no solution in js, explain me how I can add exif to canvas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my best to understand your question darkiron so here is my attempt at answering

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/20w7u4qc/

javascript

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.translate(-c.width / 2, -c.height / 2);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```

Let me know if it is wrong or if you update your question to be understandable :)