# How to curve a texture by offsetting X Pixels

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Refer to this fiddle:

```js
// get canvas references (canvas=collar, canvas1=texture)
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

// preload the texture and collar images before starting

var textureImg, collarImg;
var imageURLs = [];
var imagesOK = 0;
var imgs = [];
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/checkered.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/collar.png");
loadAllImages();

function loadAllImages(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function () {
            imagesOK++;
            if (imagesOK == imageURLs.length) {
                textureImg = imgs[0];
                collarImg = imgs[1];
                start();
            }
        };
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }
}


function start() {

    // set both canvas dimensions
    canvas.width = collarImg.width;
    canvas.height = collarImg.height + 5;
    canvas1.width = textureImg.width;
    canvas1.height = textureImg.height;

    // draw the textureImg on canvas1
    ctx1.drawImage(textureImg, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);

    // curve the texture into a collar shaped curved 
    curveTexture(collarImg.width, collarImg.height);

    // draw the collarImg on canvas
    ctx.drawImage(collarImg, 0, 0);

    // set compositing to source-atop
    // any new drawing will ONLY fill existing non-transparent pixels
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

    // draw the curved texture from canvas1 onto the collar of canvas
    // (the existing pixels are the collar, so only the collar is filled)
    ctx.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);



}

function curveTexture(w, h) {

    // define a quadratic curve that fits the collar bottom
    // These values change if the collar image changes (+5,-32)
    var x0 = 0;
    var y0 = h + 5;
    var cx = w / 2;
    var cy = h - 32;
    var x1 = w;
    var y1 = h + 5;

    // get a,b,c for quadratic equation
    // equation is used to offset columns of texture pixels
    // in the same shape as the collar
    var Q = getQuadraticEquation(x0, y0, cx, cy, x1, y1);

    // get the texture canvas pixel data
    // 2 copies to avoid self-referencing
    var imageData0 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    var data0 = imageData0.data;
    var imageData1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    var data1 = imageData1.data;

    // loop thru each vertical column of pixels
    // Offset the pixel column into the shape of the quad-curve
    for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            // the pixel to write
            var n = ((w * y) + x) * 4;
            // the vertical offset amount
            var yy = parseInt(y + h - (Q.a * x * x + Q.b * x + Q.c));
            // the offset pixel to read
            var nn = ((w * yy) + x) * 4;

            // offset this pixel by the quadCurve Y value (yy)
            data0[n + 0] = data1[nn + 0];
            data0[n + 1] = data1[nn + 1];
            data0[n + 2] = data1[nn + 2];
            data0[n + 3] = data1[nn + 3];
        }
    }
    ctx1.putImageData(imageData0, 0, 0);
}


// Quadratic Curve: given x coordinate, find y coordinate
function getQuadraticY(x, Q) {
    return (Q.a * x * x + Q.b * x + Q.c);
}

// Quadratic Curve: 
// Given: start,control,end points
// Find: a,b,c in quadratic equation ( y=a*x*x+b*x+c )
function getQuadraticEquation(x0, y0, cx, cy, x2, y2) {
    // need 1 more point on q-curve, so calc its midpoint XY
    // Note: since T=0.5 therefore TT=(1-T)=0.5 also [so could simplify]
    var T = 0.50;
    var TT = 1 - T;
    var x1 = TT * TT * x0 + 2 * TT * T * cx + T * T * x2;
    var y1 = TT * TT * y0 + 2 * TT * T * cy + T * T * y2;
    var A = ((y1 - y0) * (x0 - x2) + (y2 - y0) * (x1 - x0)) / ((x0 - x2) * (x1 * x1 - x0 * x0) + (x1 - x0) * (x2 * x2 - x0 * x0));
    var B = ((y1 - y0) - A * (x1 * x1 - x0 * x0)) / (x1 - x0);
    var C = y0 - A * x0 * x0 - B * x0;
    return ({
        a: A,
        b: B,
        c: C
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: ivory;
    padding:20px;
}
canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>"Curve" a texture</h3>
<p>by offsetting Y pixels based on Q-curve</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<p>The temporary texture canvas (canvas1)</p>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hdXyk/

I want to convert that horizontal generated lines to vertical. I tries to change the values but unable to achieved it.

I think that "Curve" a texture by offsetting X pixels based on Q-curve might work for getting vertical lines. Please help me for this.

For more you can refer this link : [How to fill pattern in canvas and curving along the shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811066/how-to-fill-pattern-in-canvas-and-curving-along-the-shape)

Comment: What about rotating the image 90 degree? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287390/javascript-canvas-rotate-image).

Comment: I tried that part but unable to get the elbow shape. I think for elbow shape/curve, we need to do offset in X pixel. @SangbokLee

Comment: Refer this link for correct Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712312/how-to-convert-image-pixel-into-s-curve-shape-in-canvas