# How to convert image pixel into s-curve shape in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, bezier

I have such type of image [image: fabric-pattern]

I want that what we are seeing straight lines in image (actually which are pixel), it should get converted into the S-curve. I have implemented C-type of curve using canvas and its properties, but unable to do S-curve.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want each vertical line to follow a "S"?

If that's the case you can use f.ex. `Math.sin()` combined with `drawImage()` and its clipping parameters to slice the image per pixel column while displacing the slice based on the sin().

The key formulas are:

```
var step = Math.PI * 2 / w;
```

this maps a full circle to the width of the canvas so that when reaching the end we'll be back to the start point, in this case forming a S-curve.

```
var y = Math.sin(step * x) * scale;
```

This calculates the displacement on y-axis based on the previously calculated step value, now linked to x position. This produces a value between -1 and 1, so we need to scale it up. Scale represents maximum radius in number of pixels.

## Example

[image: snapshot]

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");           // just some inits for demo
var img = new Image;
img.onload = slice;
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UvqUP.gif";

function slice() {
  var w = c.width = this.width;
  var h = c.height = this.height;
  var step = Math.PI * 2 / w;           // full circle / width of canvas
  var scale = 75;                       // max displacement on y
  
  for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    ctx.drawImage(this,
      x, 0, 1, h,                       // source line from image
      x, Math.sin(step*x)*scale, 1, h); // displaced line
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

On the x-axis (obviously not as visible in this case since the changes happens along the lines and there are other methods that could be used such as over-drawing with an s-shape at each end):

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");           // just some inits for demo
var img = new Image;
img.onload = slice;
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UvqUP.gif";

function slice() {
  var w = c.width = this.width;
  var h = c.height = this.height;
  var step = Math.PI * 2 / h;           // full circle / width of canvas
  var scale = 75;                       // max displacement on y
  
  for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    ctx.drawImage(this,
      0, y, w, 1,                       // source line from image
      Math.sin(step*y)*scale, y, w, 1); // displaced line
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: And If I want that in vertical shape then what changes did I need to there @K3N

Comment: Just swap the arguments for the drawImage, ie. using y name instead of x in the for-loop: (this, 0, y, w, 1,  Math.sin(step*y)*scale, y, w, 1). And of course, step = Math.PI * 2 / h instead.

Comment: You are champ mann,just champ. I had wasted my two days in this by scathing my head here and there.Thanks buddy. @K3N

Comment: Thanks buddy. Thank you very much. @K3N

Comment: Will you please upload old snippet which you posted back some mins ago.by mistakenly I told it wrong and that why i deleted my comment as soon as I realized it. @K3N

Comment: @Mohammed I haven't removed any comment/snippet. I actually added the horizontal variation to the answer instead. Not sure what you have in mind?

Comment: Ok.My mistake. Thanks once again for this. @K3N

Comment: What Should I change I want to make it as 'V' shape curve? @K3N