# How to convert image pixel into )|( -curve shape in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, bezier

I have an image with the following pattern:

[image]

I want to convert the straight lines in the image into a )|( shape. I have implemented C-type and S-type curves using canvas and its properties, but I am unable to do )|(-curve.

How can I do this?

Comment: yes you can visit here for mockup : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712312/how-to-convert-image-pixel-into-s-curve-shape-in-canvas @Kaiido

Comment: I tried to use that technique but i think I am making mistake some hwere. But not getting where?

Comment: yes you are very correct  some thing like that. But it should be look like )|( something like this a straight line between two inverted 'c'

Comment: do the actual lines all need to generate differently, or are you just looking for "how to [warp](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/warp-images-shapes-paths.html) this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712312/how-to-convert-image-pixel-into-s-curve-shape-in-canvas) slightly and have the halve sin range applied to the width (or height) as an offset, then take that offset x 2 and subtract from the total height of the new line.

What happens is that the sin() function will take an input and produce a new value between [0.0, 1.0]. Normally you would combine sin+cos to produce a circle, but we only need the value from one axis, and since we only need more of a ellipse shape we scale with a smaller value than radius (image size would represents diameter on the axis you're after).

[image: snapshot]

So with the couple of modifications on the code I made in the other answer:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");           // just some inits for demo
var img = new Image;
img.onload = slice;
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UvqUP.gif";

function slice() {
  var w = c.width = this.width;
  var h = c.height = this.height;
  var step = Math.PI / w;               // half circle / width of canvas
  var scale = 75;                       // max displacement on y
  
  for(var x = 0, offset; x < w; x++) {
    offset = Math.sin(step*x)*scale;
    ctx.drawImage(this,
      x, 0, 1, h,                       // source line from image
      x, offset, 1, h - offset*2);      // displaced line
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

(for vertical effect just reference where the changes are in the previous answer and apply offset instead of the formula).

Comment: thanks everyone for this help. One more thing If I would like to generate oval lines shape of my posted image in question starting from one of the corner of that image. Then what should I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the distance from the horizontal center to apply a sin wave to the image scale. You only want part of the sin wave (PI/2 to PI) or (cos 0 to PI/2)

```js
var img = new Image;
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UvqUP.gif";
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
img.onload = function () {
    var w,h,ch,cw,amount,x,scale;
    w = can.width = this.width;
    h = can.height = this.height;
    cw = w / 2;
    ch = h / 2;
    amount = 50;  // amount to bend in pixels
    amount *= 1 / ch;  // convert to unit scale
    for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
     scale = 1.0 - (Math.cos(((cw - x) / cw) * Math.PI * 0.5)) * amount;
        ctx.drawImage(this, x, 0, 1, h, x, ch - ch * scale , 1, h * scale); 
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```

Comment: isnt this almost a blanket copy of k3ns code in the linked answer in comments at top?

Comment: @torox posted this 17 hours ago and did not copy anything.

Comment: @torox in fact if anything has been copied it has been from my answer. Look at the posting times and see who was first.

Comment: torox: Not that it matters since the code is relativ generic, but it seem to be a copy from my answer (not in this post, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42714976/1693593) >24h). You see that by the *image link* which points to the image in the other question, not to the one in the top of this question (PcYq9.gif). A few vars got new names, the rest pretty similar, `new Image` wo/ parenthesis, double decl. of x.. the formula is naturally changed to match the question here. In any case, I am OK with people copying my code (not so much if they do and pretend they didn't). Anyways..

Comment: @Blindman67 I think torox means [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42714976/1693593)

Comment: @K3N I got the image link from a fiddle posted by Kaiido.

Comment: @Blindman67 alright, thanks. Seems the code from my answer took a long circle and ended up here (the code still seem to be copied, just from the fiddle instead). Anyways, closed case on my part.

Comment: @K3N this answer is MY code, the solution is uniquely mine and was not copied from anyone.