# How to convert the image pixel into ellipse using canvas and Bezier

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, bezier

I have the following type of image:

[image]

what I want is to generate a bezier curve pattern such that it should converted into this ellipse  pattern curves:

[image]

Only Cuff part not sleeves Part. Please Help me for this.

For an idea you can visit this link [How to convert image pixel into )|( -curve shape in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733727/how-to-convert-image-pixel-into-curve-shape-in-canvas)

Comment: so that was for this type of application... You would have saved yourself a lot of time by learning how to apply a texture on a 3d model in webgl.But I'll keep an eye on a possible 2d solution

Comment: Thanks for webgl suggestion, I m going through it. Possibly, If you find any answer regarding this then please help me. @Kaiido

Comment: webgl Solution from you also appreciated. @Kaiido

Comment: I only have time for comments currently, but I'm sure you'll get something, moreover if you do some little searches.

Comment: Yes I am working on that.@Kaiido

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking. you have a 2D image, and you want to turn it into 3D geometry? If so, the obvious answer is: do that. Find a library or framework that lets you define a 3D surface that you can apply a 2D texture to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you can refer K3N's answer for my previous question is somewhat related to that only.I m trying since yesterday to achieve this but unable to make a curve form.

Comment: Remember that stackoverflow questions and answers are meant to be useful to more than just you - a good question is self contained, if it "builds on" another question, include enough information in this one that it can be understood in isolation. I've seen your other question, I even commented on it before, and I still don't understand what you want here. One image is a pattern, the other image is a picture of a sleeve with a completely different pattern: these are not good examples. Please draw, or find, something that illustrates your need better.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I changed the other image to cuff.Now point is I only want to generate such bezier curves of image1 that should be like the curves in image two.For reference you can refer that link in question.Hope you get what I want to convey.

Comment: Yes but what *curve* in image 2? You seem to be talking about things that you assume we understand, without a good explanation. Can you should, with some pictures, hand draw them if you have to, what parts of image 1 map to what parts of image 2. Again: questions need to be understandable on their own, because questions on Stackoverflow are for solving problems that you can describe in a single question post. Linking to another question is fine but not for primary details.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There is no any particular part of image1 which I like to map on image 2. If you go through link which I posted in above quested, there was thing like )|( generated through js.Similar thing I want to implemented i.e. want to generate such curves structure which you are seeing in image2  on image 1.Sorry if I am again unable to clear your idea.

Comment: **again**: you want to turn one pattern into another pattern, but the two images you show are incompatible patterns as whole images, so can you PLEASE explain, in this post, what part of image 2 you are trying to map image 1 onto. Are you trying to turn straight lines into ellipses (e.g. the cuff), are you trying to turn straight lines into an impossible shape that is ellipses plus perpendicular lines (the cuff plus sleeve), *what single transformation, or multiple separate translations, are you looking for, and why can you not show this with normal images instead of unrelated images*

Comment: seriously, just draw something yourself, take a photo of it, and show it in your question here - pretend we're all 5: your question, even with the link, does not explain what you *want*, it's not clear enough. So please update your post to be clearer.

Comment: Ya I want to turn straight lines into ellipses (e.g. the cuff) using canvas and js @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: okay, so if you want to know how to turn lines into ellipses, don't ask about turning things into "a cuff", because there are too many ways to interpret what that means. Now that we know what you actually need, can you update your title and question text to ask this "how to turn straight lines into ellipses" question instead? That way people are much better able to help out.

Comment: Updated @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans